# C Preprocessor Syntax

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to do something like this with the C preprocessor?
If it's possible, what is the correct syntax?
I would expect to see "5" as an answer, but I am getting "7".
Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ENABLE_FEATURE_1   true
#define ENABLE_FEATURE_2   false
#define ENABLE_FEATURE_3   true

#if (ENABLE_FEATURE_1 == true)
    #define FT_BIT_0    1
#else
    #define FT_BIT_0    0
#endif

#if (ENABLE_FEATURE_2 == true)
    #define FT_BIT_1    2
#else
    #define FT_BIT_1    0
#endif

#if (ENABLE_FEATURE_3 == true)
    #define FT_BIT_2    4
#else
    #define FT_BIT_2    0
#endif

#define ENABLED_FEATURES (FT_BIT_0 + FT_BIT_1 + FT_BIT_2)

int main() {
  printf("Enabled Features: %i", ENABLED_FEATURES);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. But you need defines for `true` and `false` (or at least `true`), otherwise the preprocessor will treat such unresolvable tokens in preprocessor conditionals as 0 (see [6.10.1p4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.1p4)), which is why you're getting 7 not 5 in your output (both `true` and `false` are treated as `0` in the conditionals and since `0 == 0`, all *BIT* macro get set to their non-zero versions).

`#include`ing `<stdbool.h>` will provide the defines. They are [guaranteed to be (7.18)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.18):

```
#define true 1
#define false 0
```